# Maven downloading dependency from Sonatype causing AbstractMethodError

Tags: java, maven, neo4j, tinkerpop

I am seeing a strange issue where when I add a jar I downloaded from Sonatype myself using the system path, everything works fine, but when I try downloading directly from the Sonatype repository, I get an AbstractMethodError once I run my code.

Adding the jar myself, from https://oss.sonatype.org/index.html#nexus-search;quick~neo4j2:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.tinkerpop.blueprints</groupId>
    <artifactId>blueprints-neo4j2-graph</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <scope>system</scope>
    <systemPath>${project.basedir}/../../../blueprints/blueprints-neo4j2-graph/target/blueprints-neo4j2-   graph-2.5.0-SNAPSHOT.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

Here is how I add the Sonatype repository and the dependency to my pom.xml:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>sonatype-nexus-snapshots</id>
        <name>Sonatype Nexus Snapshots</name>
        <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>

...

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.tinkerpop.blueprints</groupId>
        <artifactId>blueprints-neo4j2-graph</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I'm not sure what the issue could be since the jar is fine. Can anyone figure this out?

AbstractMethodError:

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.neo4j.kernel.impl.cache.CacheProvider.newNodeCache(Lorg/neo4j/kernel/impl/util/StringLogger;Lorg/neo4j/kernel/configuration/Config;Lorg/neo4j/kernel/monitoring/Monitors;)Lorg/neo4j/kernel/impl/cache/Cache;
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.DefaultCaches.node(DefaultCaches.java:51)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.create(InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.java:522)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.run(InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.java:301)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase.<init>(EmbeddedGraphDatabase.java:63)
    at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory$1.newDatabase(GraphDatabaseFactory.java:92)
    at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseBuilder.newGraphDatabase(GraphDatabaseBuilder.java:198)
    at com.tinkerpop.blueprints.impls.neo4j2.Neo4j2Graph.<init>(Neo4j2Graph.java:153)
    at com.tinkerpop.blueprints.impls.neo4j2.Neo4j2Graph.<init>(Neo4j2Graph.java:135)
    at com.seeq.appserver.driver.graph.specific.Neo4jSpecific.openConnection(Neo4jSpecific.java:22)
    at com.seeq.appserver.driver.graph.specific.GraphSpecific$openConnection.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:42)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:112)
    at com.seeq.appserver.driver.graph.blueprints.BlueprintsDriver.openConnection(BlueprintsDriver.groovy:68)
    at com.seeq.appserver.driver.graph.blueprints.ITBlueprintsDriverNeo4j.oneTimeSetUp(ITBlueprintsDriverNeo4j.java:14)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

Dependency tree:

```
[INFO] +- com.tinkerpop.rexster:rexster-protocol:jar:2.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.tinkerpop.rexster:rexster-core:jar:2.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.sun.jersey:jersey-json:jar:1.17:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:jar:2.2.3-1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:jar:2.2.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |     +- javax.xml.stream:stax-api:jar:1.0-2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |     \- javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-jaxrs:jar:1.9.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-xc:jar:1.9.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- com.sun.jersey:jersey-core:jar:1.17:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:jar:3.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.tinkerpop.gremlin:gremlin-groovy:jar:2.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.tinkerpop.gremlin:gremlin-java:jar:2.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.0.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.ivy:ivy:jar:2.3.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:jar:1.8.9:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- asm:asm:jar:3.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- asm:asm-commons:jar:3.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- asm:asm-util:jar:3.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- asm:asm-analysis:jar:3.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- asm:asm-tree:jar:3.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.ant:ant:jar:1.8.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apache.ant:ant-launcher:jar:1.8.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.fusesource.jansi:jansi:jar:1.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.tinkerpop:pipes:jar:2.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.msgpack:msgpack:jar:0.6.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.15.0-GA:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.codehaus.jettison:jettison:jar:1.3.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- stax:stax-api:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.glassfish.grizzly:grizzly-framework:jar:2.2.16:compile
[INFO] +- com.tinkerpop.blueprints:blueprints-core:jar:2.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-json-org:jar:2.1.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.1.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.1.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.json:json:jar:20090211:compile
[INFO] |  +- colt:colt:jar:1.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- concurrent:concurrent:jar:1.3.4:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-configuration:commons-configuration:jar:1.6:compile
[INFO] |     +- commons-digester:commons-digester:jar:1.8:compile
[INFO] |     |  \- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.7.0:compile
[INFO] |     \- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils-core:jar:1.8.0:compile
[INFO] +- com.tinkerpop.blueprints:blueprints-neo4j2-graph:jar:2.5.0-SNAPSHOT:system
[INFO] +- org.neo4j:neo4j:jar:2.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.neo4j:neo4j-kernel:jar:2.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-jta_1.1_spec:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.neo4j:neo4j-lucene-index:jar:2.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.lucene:lucene-core:jar:3.6.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.neo4j:neo4j-graph-algo:jar:2.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.neo4j:neo4j-udc:jar:2.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.neo4j:neo4j-graph-matching:jar:2.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.neo4j:neo4j-cypher:jar:2.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.neo4j:neo4j-cypher-commons:jar:2.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.neo4j:neo4j-cypher-compiler-1.9:jar:2.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.neo4j:neo4j-cypher-compiler-2.0:jar:2.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.parboiled:parboiled-scala_2.10:jar:1.1.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     \- org.parboiled:parboiled-core:jar:1.1.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.scala-lang:scala-library:jar:2.10.3:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.neo4j:neo4j-jmx:jar:2.0.1:compile
```

Comment: Can you show your maven dependency tree? `mvn dependency:tree`

Comment: The only thing I can think of right now is that you are using version 2.0.1 and the tinkerpop snapshot is using version 2.0.0. Maybe there's a version conflict. Also, use the same version of all the tikerpop modules (2.4.0. or 2.5.0-SNAPSHOT for all).